# Strange issue with setting custom foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

From the documentation I read that:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "Patron", foreign_key: "patron_id"
end
```

so according to that I'm trying the next:

```
class Choco < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kinds, inverse_of: :choco, foreign_key: :myhash
```

and

```
class Kind < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :choco, foreign_key: :myhash
```

But instead it pastes in that column NULL and I cannot understand why.

**Schema**

For Choco:

```
— (id, title, myhash)
```

For Kind:

```
— (id, choco_id, title)
```

I want to paste myhash on choco_id field on creating a new kind.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify primary key to store on `Kind` model:

```
class Choco < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'myhash'
  has_many :kinds, inverse_of: :choco, primary_key: :myhash


class Kind < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :choco, primary_key: :myhash
```

So `choco_id` column in `Kind` model will store `myhash` value of choco.

Comment: then I should remove this part `foreign_key: :myhash` from `Choco`?

Comment: @J.Doe Add `self.primary_key = 'myhash'` in your `Choco` model.

Comment: nope. The same thing =/ I've tried this one too yesterday, but again no luck

Comment: @J.Doe Okay, how about if you use `belongs_to :choco, primary_key: 'myhash'` in `Kind` model and remove `primary_key: :myhash` in `Choco` model?

Comment: again - no =/ the same thing. It pastes there Choco's ID, not `myhash`

Comment: @J.Doe Ok so you need to create a migration like in my answer to remove `id` column in `Choco` model.

Comment: but what if I need this column too? Because my other table is connected to it via `id` column =/ is that the only solution?

Comment: Well, base on document you can implement your way with `has_many :kinds, inverse_of: :choco, primary_key: :myhash` but somehow it does not works in your case, so I think this may be the only solution. Or you can try adding `primary_key: 'myhash'` in both `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations to see if it works.

Comment: oh, it works now! BUT! My hash was `771abc...` and it wrote there only `771` part. For that I change my `choco_id` column type to `string`, but now it gives the next error: `invalid input syntax for integer: 771abc...`. How to fix that?

Comment: when I tried to add a new `kind`, it does not add and gives in the console those error

Comment: did you create a migration to change column type of `choco_id` from integer to string?

Comment: Try to remove and add `choco_id` with type `string` again, its type seems does not update yet.

Comment: Tha last thing is: When I'm creating a new choco it redirects to `edit` and here I get ` 
{"controller"=>"Chocos", "action"=>"edit", "id"=>"18f68088-9a10-799ab45f464d"}` and error: `invalid input syntax for integer:` how can I fix that? By the way, thanks for your help!

Comment: I see, `18f68088-9a10-799ab45f464d` is your `myhash` right? You need to change this code `Choco.find(params[:id])` in your controller to something like this: `Choco.find_by(myhash: params[:id])`. The old code will search chocos with value of id column = `18f68088-9a10-799ab45f464d`, and that will cause `invalid input syntax for integer` error.